# Playing the MIDI at the iOS from Delphi XE - 5

Tags: ios, delphi, midi

is there way how to play MIDI from the Delphi at iPhone under Delphi XE-5?

I found different articles showing how to play the MIDI under ObjectC so the iOS from version 5.0 has that support, but there is missing AudioToolbox and CoreMIDI implementation at the Delphi.

Does someone have that?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using XE-5 because you're attempting to build a cross-platform app.   You're up against a fundamental problem that some of the platforms supported by XE5 don't have MIDI at all.

However you approach this, you will need to build platform specific portions of the app to handle MIDI on iOS. The AudioToolbox API is a C API and CoreMIDI is Objective-C.  Either way, you need to learn how to create Objective-C and C language bindings in Delphi, and consider writing a large part of your app using the platform's native tools and language.

A quick search with google suggests that you should be looking at the `OCClass` bridge.

Comment: CoreMIDI is plain C, not objective C.

Comment: Traditionally on MacOS X it certainly was a C API. On iOS seemingly it's [Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/_index.html)

Comment: Only the MIDInetwork* stuff is ObjC. MIDI Services is identical to the OS X version.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually checking if there isn't somebody who already wrote the PAS unit for that. But I see that probably not, so I start to write it my self. Actually it's so many code that I'm writing a parser can that can convert any iOS .h file to .PAS file.

I'll update this thread once I'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there isn't any solution so far.

So I wrote my self a tool to convert the iOS .h units into the .PAS.

It's in progress but I have already first units.

http://pjstrnad.com/my-projects/delphi-implementation-missing-ios-frameworks/

I'll appreciate if you can give me feedback. My intention is to convert completely the iOS framework so Delphi developers can use all the features of the iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: I just uploaded all the missing units to http://pjstrnad.com/my-projects/delphi-implementation-missing-ios-frameworks/. They looks working on the simulator, but doesn't work on the iPhone because the AudioUnit has no code inside the framework. Any idea why it's like that?